# Sorting a list of files

Tags: unix, sorting

Maybe am missing something but how do i sort in a descending order a list with this naming

```
B7
B40
B41
B42
B8
B43
B20
B45
B53
B47
B48
B5
B6
```

`sort -n` does not sort the way i would like

```
B5
B6
B7
```

and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
sort -k1.2n
```

This sorts by (the data starting at) the second char (`2`) of the first column (`1`), assuming numerical data (`n`).